Use slicer to dynamically select column
How can I use a slicer to dynamically select a column from my table?  I want to have two slicers: the first to select the function and the second to select the column.  I can get the first slicer working, but having issues with the second.
I’ve tried
    FinalValue = 
    VAR Func = SELECTEDVALUE(StatFunctionSelector[Function])
    VAR Col = SELECTEDVALUE(FieldParameter[Parameter])

RETURN SWITCH(Func, 
"Average", AVERAGE(Table1[Col]), 
"Max", MAX(Table1[Col]), 
"Min", MIN(Table1[Col]),
"Sum", SUM(Table1[Col]), 
"Count", COUNT(Table1[Col]), 
"StdDev", STDEV.P(Table1[Col]))

I’d rather avoid having to spell each permutation out explicitly.
For example, if I have columns
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
I’d like to have to a slider that lets you select which function to apply (average, min, max, etc.) and then another slicer that selects which column to use.
For example, if selected “Average” and “A”, I’d get the average of column A.

Can u share some data ? Expected output ?

Did you try using parameters?

@AmiraBedhiafi added an example

@ttruhcheva I tried using a field parameter, but can’t get it to work in my measure.

post your measure calculation.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to refer to a column using a string in DAX. So you would need to spell out each permutation like the following measure:
Measure = 
VAR Func = SELECTEDVALUE(StatFunctionSelector[Function])
VAR Col = SELECTEDVALUE(StatColumnSelector[Column])

VAR output = 
SWITCH( Col,
"A", SWITCH(Func, 
    "Average", CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table1[A])),
    "Max", CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[A])),
    "Min", CALCULATE(MIN(Table1[A])),
    "Sum", CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[A])),
    "Count", CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[A])),
    "StdDev", CALCULATE(STDEV.P(Table1[A])),
    BLANK()),
"B", SWITCH(Func, 
    "Average", CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table1[B])),
    "Max", CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[B])),
    "Min", CALCULATE(MIN(Table1[B])),
    "Sum", CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[B])),
    "Count", CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[B])),
    "StdDev", CALCULATE(STDEV.P(Table1[B])),
    BLANK())

)

RETURN output

StatFunctionSelector Table:
StatFunctionSelector = 
DATATABLE(
    "Function", STRING,
    {
        {"Average"},
        {"Max"},
        {"Min"},
        {"Sum"},
        {"Count"},
        {"StdDev"}
    }
)

StatColumnSelector Table:
StatColumnSelector = 
DATATABLE(
    "Column", STRING,
    {
        {"A"},
        {"B"},
        {"C"},
        {"D"}
    }
)

